# How do i set my text fields to take in information in conjunction with the items selected on my Spinners?

Tags: java, android, button, spinner, textfield

If you run my application at the moment, you'll see that i have 2 spinners and 2 text fields. I have the top spinner limited to 4 digits and i want the application to convert between decimal, binary, hex, and such. That part i know how to do, but i can't get my text field to understand that when the user selects "Binary" it uses the convertToBinary function and if they select decimal- it convertsToDecimal.

Thank of this application like a google translate. The user chooses the top spinner "binary" then uses the text field below it to input the binary value "0010" and then uses the second spinner to select WHICH they want the first text field to convert to- so if they choose "decimal" as the second spinner option- when the user hits CONVERT the  output (answer) displays in the second text field below the second spinner.

This is all of my Code.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.overworldinnovations.datatool;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {


private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
private Button buttonConvert;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //addItemsOnSpinner2();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();   

    }
}

/*public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }*/

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
  }

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);

    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "OnClickListener : " + 
                "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
                "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonConvert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="Convert" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Please Select A Data Type To Be Converted"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:entries="@array/type_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/data_prompt" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:entries="@array/type_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/data_prompt" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:maxLength="4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Data Tool</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="convert">Convert</string>
<string name="data_tool_is_an_application_that_converts_binary_to_decimal_d">Data Tool is an application that converts Binary to Decimal :D</string>
<string name ="data_prompt">Choose a data type</string>

<string-array name = "type_arrays">
    <item >Decimal</item>
    <item >Binary</item>
    <item >Hexidecimal</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: What you need is a conversion table.  Essentially, one spinner is the row, the other spinner is the column.  Put them both together and you have the formula you need to run.  I did this exact same thing for a measurement converter I wrote a bit ago.  Not to blatantly plug the app.  But it can be found here: http://dpoisn.com/demos/AndroidDev/miniapps/default.php

Comment: With the code i have already- how do i actually incorporate the functions into my app?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to better explain what to do.

I haven't got the time to write the actual code.  But you should be able to figure it out from this sort-of pseudo code with explanation.

Your spinners need to hold the complete lists of both conversions.  I'll use Inches to Centimeters as an example.  Each spinner will have both as options, and send the values 0 or 1.

You need to create a 2 dimensional array for your conversion table:

```
inchesToCent[0][0] = 1
inchesToCent[0][1] = 2.54
inchesToCent[1][0] = .393
inchesToCent[1][1] = 1
```

When someone makes their choices in the spinners, their options will always return, 0 or 1 for each.  The simple equation that follows is this:

```
result = valueEntered * inchesToCent[spinner1][spinner2]
```

Essentially what this says is that you can take whatever value is in the "please convert this" entry, and multiply that against the choices made in the spinners.

So if spinner1_choice=0 and spinner2_choice=1 and they entered 5, your equation will evaluate to:

```
5 * 2.54 = 12.7
```

You can create the array list to hold any values.  You can have any number of items in the array.  Just make sure that both lists appear in both spinners.
I recommend creating the table in Excel to visually see what the 2 dimensional array looks like.  Something like this:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
|        | inches | cents |
+--------+--------+-------+
| inches |    1   |  2.54 |
+--------+--------+-------+
| cents  |  .393  |   1   |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

All the elements are here to explain the correct way to do this,  Let me know if you need additional help.